# enum and cases in swift

Tags: swift, enums

1. I dont really get what is the point of defining `enum` and what it does
2. how come when the input type is `Int` we do have both `1` and some other strings as our cases
3. what is `rawValue`.

```
enum Rank : Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case Jack, Queen, King 

    func simpleDirection() -> String {
        switch self {
            case .Ace:
               return "Ace"
            case .Jack:
                return "Jack"
            case .Queen:
                return "Queen"
            case .King:
                return "King"
            default: 
                return String (self.rawValue)
        }
    }
}

let ace = Rank.Ace
let aceRawValue = ace.rawValue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enums are a way to tell the type system that the type (Rank) can only have  the values you specify (Two, Three and so on). The compiler will throw an error if you try to set a variable of type Rank to 54. It is also more readable to humans to use Rank.Ace instead of just the number 1.
2. The values auto increment so Two has a raw value of 2, Three has 3 and so on.
3. The raw value is the number that the compiled program will use to represent the values in the enum. The compiled program has no notion of Rank or its allowed values.

To condense it, enums help the type system at compile time to stop you from accidentally using improper card values. At runtime, enums are represented by their rawValue.

For more specific info on Swift enums, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html. For instance, Swift allows you to enforce the enum at runtime by automatically creating an initializer that creates an optional enum value from a rawValue (see the section "Initializing from a Raw Value").

Comment: what does exactly self refer to ? Is that what ever we put in cases ? :)

Comment: In instance methods such as `simpleDirection` `self` refers to the object on which the method is invoked. For example, if we were to call `ace.simpleDirection()`, `self` would refer to `ace`. The switch statement in your example just compares `self` to the various enum values.